# New sub-class is not loading for Rails tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a super class `class Handlers::AlertHandler` in my app with various sub classes like `EmailAlertHandler`, `SmsAlertHandler` etc. I also created another sub-class, `TestAlertHandler`, in order to unit test the generic alert functionality.

```
├ lib
│  └ models
│     └ handlers
│        ├ alert_handler.rb
│        ├ email_alert_handler.rb
│        └ website_alert_handler.rb
└ test
   └ models
      ├ alert_observer_test.rb   <= this is my problematic test class
      └ handlers
         └ test_alert_handler.rb
```

My tests aren't able to see or load `test_alert_handler.rb` using `include` or `require`. How do I use this class in my tests? I wan't to keep testing code in the `/test` folder.

---

**UPDATE:**
And here are my classes, if that might help. Very simple stuff. The non-test classes load fine. It is only the `TestAlertHandler` file that doesn't load.

```
class Handlers::AlertHandler
    def send_alert(object)
        throw new NotImplementedError
    end
end
```

```
class Handlers::WebsiteAlertHandler < Handlers::AlertHandler
    def send_alert(object)
        puts "!!!! HOORAY! From Website"
    end
end
```

```
class Handlers::EmailAlertHandler < Handlers::AlertHandler
    def send_alert(object)
        puts "!!!! HOORAY! From Email"
    end
end
```

```
class Handlers::TestAlertHandler < Handlers::AlertHandler
    def send_alert(object)
        puts "!!!! HOORAY! From Test"
    end
end
```

And here is the test class. I've tried many variations of `require` and `include` with no luck.

```
require 'test_helper'
require 'handlers/test_alert_handler'
class AlertObserverTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
    def setup
        @handler = TestAlertHandler.new
    end
    test "some test that never gets called because of setup"
        #...
    end
end
```

Comment: And where does `AlertObserverTest` sit? I would only expect that `require 'handlers/test_alert_handler` to work if `alert_observer_test.rb` is in `test/models`, which it sounds like maybe it is.

Comment: You are correct. The files are `test/models/alert_observer_test.rb` and `test/models/handlers/test_alert_handler.rb`. I dont know if this is the best way to structure the files, which is, of course, why I am asking this question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure if this will do it, but I think you maybe have to add `lib` to your autoload paths.

From [this somewhat related blog post I wrote](http://www.benfranklinlabs.com/where-to-put-rails-modules/):

```
# config/application.rb

module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib) # add this line
  end
end
```

Comment: Now that I look closer I'm having second thoughts. I'd be curious to see your actual test file. How are you including the files you want to test?

Comment: I already have my `lib` folder added for the normal website - thats how the non-test files are getting loaded. It is only the test file that isn't loading and I dont want to stick that in the lib folder because it is testing code. I'll add my classes in the OP.

Comment: Thanks for adding that code. I was actually hoping to see your tests files themselves as well.

Comment: Oops. Sorry. I just added the test class. I stripped out the actual test code because it never actually gets called due to `setup` getting called first.